# If I have a stationary time series with no trend or seasonality, Can still apply ARIMA model on this TS?

Tags: time-series, arima, multivariate-time-series

Results of TS decomposition[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlSm.png)

my dataset is composed of ['date', 'Sales', 'EventsA'] 'EventsA' is an aggressor, So I can't figured out what's the next step for this.

Please let know how to proceed with this in this situation

Results of TS decomposition[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFlSm.png)

my dataset is composed of ['date', 'Sales', 'EventsA'] 'EventsA' is an aggressor, So I can't figured out what's the next step for this.

Please let know how to proceed with this in this situation